# Нужно ли дробить данные при отправке через SignalR?

Tags: c#, signalr

Есть клиент-серверное решение с использованием SignalR: обычные клиенты, сервер и админ. Обычный клиент отправляет данные серверу, а потом сервер перенаправляет их админу(ам). В какой-то момент при отправке больших данных клиентом серверу(как выяснилось больше 32kb) получал ошибку и пришлось на сервере добавить в параметры это:

```
services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null;
});
```

**Да, сейчас все работает, но правильно ли это? Или включение этой опции спасает даже при отправке условно данных на 1гб?**

Я думаю разбить отправку по частям, но проблема в том, что отправляемые данные - коллекция классов(пример `IReadOnlyCollection<Details> details`, у которого есть внутри еще коллекции разного размера.

```
public class ChangeSet
{
    //разные свойства

    //какой-то список    
}

public class Details
{
    //разные свойства

    public List<ChangeSet> Added { get; set; }

    public List<ChangeSet> Removed { get; set; }
}
```

Думаю в такой ситуации нужно именно делить по байтам.
Т.е, порядок действий должен быть такой:

1. Клиент после аутентификации получает от сервера максимальный размер отправляемых данных.
2. Клиент перед каждой отправкой любых данных должен отправлять их не как `(IReadOnlyCollection<Details> details)`, а как `(byte[] chunk, int current, int total)`
3. Сервер при каждом получении данных должен их сохранять и если `current == total`, то он пытается преобразовать `byte [] chunks` в `IReadOnlyCollection<Details> details`. Если ошибка, то удаляем из списка все полученные данные от клиента.
4. Если успешно преобразовали данные, то в таком же порядке уже отправляем админу и он при получении их сам преобразует.
5. При отключении клиента нужно удалять все полученные данные по ConnectionId.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, обычно разделяют загрузку данных и соккеты. Суть соккетов в том, чтоб в реальном времени, быстро, без особых задержек получить что-то и отправить что-то. Вот условный чат, вы получаете моментально сообщение, его текст, файл, который там прикреплен грузится совсем другими способами, и только по вашему желанию. Другими словами, как по мне, лучше делать отправку больших файлов другими методами, например, простым API запросом, после чего этот запрос даст вам ID файла, который и отправляется через соккет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ неоднократно находил информацию, что большие данные лучше оптравлять не через SignalR, но не знаю почему так. Я не мерил размер коллекции из-за которой была ошибка, но может это сотни КБ и в будущем было бы максимум 10-20мб. А если говорить про отправку через http, то никогда этого не делал. Просто json туда-сюда гонял и на Java, и на C#(